# Sorting numbers in textfield in ElasticSearch

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, nest

I've a issue when sorting a field in ElasticSearch with text and numbers in the same field.

My pattern is something like this: *"text/number/year/text"*.

I'm trying sort by this, but I get something like this:

```
"hits": [
         {            
            "_source": {
               "fields": {
                  "numbered": "text/1/year/text",
                  "numbered-number": "1"
               }
            },
            "sort": [
               "1"
            ]
         },
         {            
            "_source": {
               "fields": {
                  "numbered": "text/10/year/text",
                  "numbered-number": "10"
               }
            },
            "sort": [
               "10"
            ]
         },
         {            
            "_source": {
               "fields": {
                  "numbered": "text/11/year/text",
                  "numbered-number": "11"
               }
            },
            "sort": [
               "11"
            ]
         },
         ...
          {            
            "_source": {
               "fields": {
                  "numbered": "text/19/year/text",
                  "numbered-number": "19"
               }
            },
            "sort": [
               "19"
            ]
         },
         {            
            "_source": {
               "fields": {
                  "numbered": "text/2/year/text",
                  "numbered-number": "2"
               }
            },
            "sort": [
               "2"
            ]
         },
```

Well, ElasticSearch are sorting this 1, 10, 11, 12, ..., 19, 2, 20, 21... How can I resolve this issue? I just need Natural Sort.

### UPDATED:

I try this script, but it's not working too.

```
POST myindex/_search
{
   "from": 0,
   "size": 40,
   "sort": [
      {
         "_script": {
            "type": "string",
            "script": {
               "inline": 
               "if ('fields.myfield.sort' =~ /\\d+/) { return Integer.parseInt(doc['fields.myfield.sort'].value); }"               
            },
            "order" : "asc"

         }
      }
   ],
    "_source": { "include": ["fields.myfield"] }
}
```

### Error

```
"reason": {
               "type": "null_pointer_exception",
               "reason": null
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [scripted sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting) to sort by integer value rather than lexicographically (which is how text will sort)

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<MyDocument>(s => s
    .Sort(so => so
        .Script(ss => ss
            .Script(sc => sc
                .Inline("Integer.parseInt(doc['numbered-number'].value)")
            )
        )
    )
);
```

The better way however would be to explicitly [map `numbered-number` field as an integer.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/fluent-mapping.html) In doing so, you'll be able to sort on the field as expected.

Comment: "_script": {
        "type": "string",
        "script": {
          "inline": "(int)doc['fields.myfield.raw'].value"
        } , **I used this, but I get this error : java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number**

Comment: Well, imagine the following case. I have a lot of users  called **user1, user2, ..., user11, user12, ... user19, user20, user21**. What I'm getting with the sorting field of ElasticSearch is: **user1, user11, user2, user20, user21, ...** How can I have a correct list? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Using a scripted sort is probably what you want then, and extract the user number for the user name and sort on that.

Comment: Updated the script to parse an integer from the string value.

Comment: Check my updated on question. I also try your script, but it didnt work. I forgot to mention that the name can have numbers of not. I'm running out of ideias to lead with this problem :(

Comment: You may need to play around to get the exact script that's fit for your use case, but the principle of using a scripted sort is still the same.